# how to rerun an activity when we return to it using finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have some code in Home activity which should be executed every time when I open Home Activity.So if I launch an activity form Home Activity. Then I returned back to Home Activity by finish(), Then, the code doesn't run when I returned back. What should I do to rerun Home Activity?

Comment: try calling your method to reload activity from `onResume()`

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what you are trying now that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah its work Thanx @rookieDeveloper